# Mysql Pivot Table no result showing

Tags: php, mysql

I am digging some information's about pivot table in mysql and fortunately I found something and I test it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c300/5) and also in wamp console:
[image]

both have a different data coz the one I used in wamp console is my actual database.

And unfortunately when I tested it in php there is no result unlike sqlfiddle and wamp console..

here is my script:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbmobile_class_record");

    $sql_pivot = "SET @sql = NULL;";
    $sql_pivot .= "SELECT
                  GROUP_CONCAT(
                    DISTINCT CONCAT(
                      'MAX(IF(criteria = ''',
                      criteria,
                      ''', score, NULL)) AS ',
                      CONCAT(',criteria,')
                    )
                  ) INTO @sql FROM tb_student_record;";
    $sql_pivot .= "SET @sql = CONCAT(
                  'SELECT stud_name, ', 
                  @sql, 
                  ' FROM tb_student_record GROUP BY stud_name'
                  );";
    $sql_pivot .= "PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;";
    $sql_pivot .= "EXECUTE stmt;";
    $sql_pivot .= "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql_pivot)){
        do {
            if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)){
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo $row['criteria'];
                    echo $row['stud_name'];
                    echo $row['score'];
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
        } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better encapsulate SQL batch into stored procedure and then run it with single CALL statement:

```
DELIMITER ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_pivot;
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_pivot()
 SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    SET @sql = NULL;

    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            DISTINCT CONCAT(
                'MAX(IF(criteria = ''',
                criteria,
                ''', score, NULL)) AS ',
                CONCAT(',criteria,')
            )
        ) INTO @sql FROM tb_student_record;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
        'SELECT stud_name, ',
        @sql,
        ' FROM tb_student_record GROUP BY stud_name'
    );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

From PHP:

```
mysqli_query($link, 'CALL sp_pivot();')
```

Main advantage of this approach is that you may very easy manage this with SQL tools like MySQL workbench or PHPStorm Database tools, besides both PHP and SQL code becomes easier to read and support. Also you can store source code of procedure in .sql file under git.

Comment: I also tried this to call in java and no result. But, when I tried to call the procedure in mysql workbench, the execution was successful